# Turn a values in a data frame into a vector in r or get combination of vectors without the combination of their elements

Tags: r, vector, combinations, element

I got the following problem.

I have several vectors for example:

```
v1 <- c("a","b","c")
  
v2 <- c("d","e","f")
  
v3 <- c("g","h")
```

I would like to have the combinations of the vectors, but not of the elements of a vector. So for example I would like to have a date frame that looks like this:

[Target-Data-Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM6Kn.png)

I have now done the following: I have defined a supervector and have saved the names of the vectors v1-v3 as strings:

```
 supervector <- c("v1","v2","v3")
```

and have used the command combinations from the arrangment package to make all possible combinations of v1-v3:

```
require(arrangements)
  combs <- combinations(x=c(NA,supervector),k=length(supervector),freq = c((length(supervector)-1),rep(1,length(supervector))))
```

I received the following data frame:

[Picture of combinations of the supervector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79w7u.png)

If I can get to translate the names of the vectors back now I would be done. So instead of v1 = "a","b","c" with a,b,c in each cell.

the target is to translate a value in a data frame back to a transposed vector.

If you have other ideas like Me have combinations of vectors without the permutation of the elements of a vector, then I am very grateful for this proposal. The goal is simply to have a data frame like that on the picture.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution building on your `combs` data is as follows.

```
combs %>% 
      as.data.frame %>%  
             mutate(V1 = mgsub::mgsub(V1, c("v1", "v2", "v3"), c("a, b, c", "d, e, f", "g, h")), 
                    V2 = mgsub::mgsub(V2, c("v1", "v2", "v3"), c("a, b, c", "d, e, f", "g, h")), 
                    V3 = mgsub::mgsub(V3, c("v1", "v2", "v3"), c("a, b, c", "d, e, f", "g, h"))) %>% 
                      splitstackshape::cSplit(., names(.))
```

**Output**

```
   V1_1 V1_2 V1_3 V2_1 V2_2 V2_3 V3_1 V3_2 V3_3
1: <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    a    b    c
2: <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    d    e    f
3: <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    g    h <NA>
4: <NA> <NA> <NA>    a    b    c    d    e    f
5: <NA> <NA> <NA>    a    b    c    g    h <NA>
6: <NA> <NA> <NA>    d    e    f    g    h <NA>
7:    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h <NA>
```